# Browser doesn't react to dispatchEvent

Tags: javascript, events, mouseevent, dispatchevent

I am developing an webapp where I have pdfjs running in an iframe so my users can have multible PDF's open. In the parent window the user can overlay the pdf's with annotations. So the parent window captures the mouse and I would like to send the mouse events on to the iframes using postMessage. My problem is that when I send for example a mouse wheel event to the pdf with postMessage and then use dispatchEvent to recreate the event in the iframe the file does not scroll.

I don't think my problem has anything with pdfjs to do so I created a small example:

```js
textE = document.getElementById('text');
textE.addEventListener('mousedown', textF);
textE.addEventListener('mousemove', textF);
textE.addEventListener('mouseup', textF);
textE.addEventListener('mouseover', textF);
textE.addEventListener('scroll', textF);
overlayE = document.getElementById('overlay');
overlayE.addEventListener('mousedown', overlayF);
overlayE.addEventListener('mousemove', overlayF);
overlayE.addEventListener('mouseup',   overlayF);
overlayE.addEventListener('mouseover', overlayF);
overlayE.addEventListener('scroll',    overlayF);

function textF(event) {
  if (event.type !== 'mousemove')
    console.log('text event', event.type, event);
}
function overlayF(event) {
  if (event.type !== 'mousemove')
    console.log('external event', event.type);
  overlayE = document.getElementById('overlay');
  textE.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(event.type, event));
}
```

```html
<div style="position:absolute; width:80%; height:100px;">
    <div id="text" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; overflow-y:scroll;">

        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      
    </div>
</div>

<div id="overlay" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:50%; width:30%; height:100%; background:rgba(255,128,128,0.5);">
</div>
```

Here I have a div with some text and I cover some of it with another div. I then use dispatchEvent to send on the mouse event to the text layer. So for example try to select some text starting in the white background text, then the text can be selected (be patient, the code snippet runs slowly for some reason). If you try the same clicking first in the text covered with read, text is not selected, although the eventlistener actually receives the event.

I don't understandthis, can somebody please help?

Comment: It appears to be working for me. When I mouseover the overlay, it's `mousemove` event handler fires, which triggers your custom event and then that handler fires. If you remove your 3rd argument from your `console.log()` statements (the `event`), the log will happen faster and be more readable. Also, please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Just place your code into a "code snippet", right in your question, as I've done for you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried edit my question to make my problem more clear.

Comment: The snippet runs slowly because you are asking it to log the actual event objects, so it takes a moment to gather all the properties and all the values of those objects. As I mentioned, if you remove the 3rd argument from **BOTH** of your `console.log()` statements (`event`), you will see the messages much faster.

Comment: I don't think that the fact that you can't select text in the red section has anything to do with events. You've simply got a `div` on top of the one with the actual text, so you can't interact with the contents of the one in the background. This seems to just be a layering issue. If you add `z-index:-1` to the CSS of the overlay, I think you'll get the functionality you want.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this isn't an event thing, it's a layering thing. The overlay is just that, positioned over the div with the text and therefore if you try selecting anything in the overlay, you're going to be limited to what's in the overlay.

Just make the overlay and underlay by adding `z-index:-1;` to its CSS and then you'll be able to select text in the main `div`.

```js
textE = document.getElementById('text');
textE.addEventListener('mousedown', textF);
textE.addEventListener('mousemove', textF);
textE.addEventListener('mouseup', textF);
textE.addEventListener('mouseover', textF);
textE.addEventListener('scroll', textF);
overlayE = document.getElementById('underlay');
overlayE.addEventListener('mousedown', overlayF);
overlayE.addEventListener('mousemove', overlayF);
overlayE.addEventListener('mouseup',   overlayF);
overlayE.addEventListener('mouseover', overlayF);
overlayE.addEventListener('scroll',    overlayF);

function textF(event) {
  if (event.type !== 'mousemove')
    console.log('text event', event.type);
}
function overlayF(event) {
  if (event.type !== 'mousemove')
    console.log('external event', event.type);
  overlayE = document.getElementById('underlay');
  textE.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(event.type, event));
}
```

```html
<div style="position:absolute; width:80%; height:100px;">
    <div id="text" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; overflow-y:scroll;">

        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      
    </div>
</div>

<div id="underlay" style="position:absolute; z-index:-1; top:0; left:50%; width:30%; height:100%; background:rgba(255,128,128,0.5);">
</div>
```

Comment: I understand your solution, but unfortunately I cannot use it. my problem is that I am displaying a PDF using the pdfjs npm module in an iframe and it is not transparent and I want to display markups in front of it. So if I set my markup layer to z-index: -1 you cannot see it. That was why I hoped to find a solution like using dispatchEvent to 'recreate' the event captured by the markup layer in the iframe pdf layer.